# How to solve, craco: *** Cannot find ESLint loader (eslint-loader). *** error with ANTd and React (2021)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using ANTd with a React application I am building for a school project. The App runs fine however, on startup I get the following: `craco: *** Cannot find ESLint loader (eslint-loader). ***` which is concerning. I have looked into this and apparently this link https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/pull/219 offers support for the issue. I am not advanced enough to know how to apply this fix to my own React project and I feel myself and other beginners would benefit greatly from an explanation on how to do so. Thanks to whoever can help!

Answer (score 6):

For react, this happens when we have `DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true` in our environment variable (or in the `.env.production` file). Instead, we should disable ESLint in craco.

Remove `DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true` from environment variable or env file.
Then in `craco.config.js`, add this:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  eslint: {
    enable: false
  },
  // ...
}
```

Or this if above doesn't work: (thanks to [@tomasz-lenarcik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2817257/tomasz-lenarcik) in the comments)

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  eslint: null,
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I've found out that with the latest version of craco (i.e. `6.4.2`) this method only works if I set `eslint: null`.

Comment: This worked for me. Steps I followed:


1. Removed node_modules directory

2. In craco.config.js, add this:

`
module.exports = {
  // ...
  eslint: {
    enable: false
  },
  // ...
}
`

3. run npm install
4. run npm start

Comment: @RushyNova is it same as the one i wrote above?

Comment: @zhuhang.jasper yes, as per the one you wrote above. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: @TomaszLenarcik thanks, added your tip into the answer!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got the same error when creating a react app with tailwindcss and typescript and running npm start:

```
npx create-react-app react-app --template craco-tailwindcss-typescript
cd react-app
npm start
```

I removed postcss.config.js and paste the following to craco.config.js then the issue is not happening any more.

```
/* eslint-disable */
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");

module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcssOptions: {
      plugins: [tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'), require('autoprefixer')]
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me too. Run npm install after making changes in craco.config profile

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33571056)

Answer (score -7):

Was an easy fix.

In package.json replace/add the following dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "antd-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.1.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
    "antd": "^4.12.2",
    "craco-less": "^1.17.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
```

Comment: How is that easy? You're saying that installing a bunch of packages with specific versions solves the problem??

Comment: PR https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/pull/219 has not mentioned to install these extra packages.