# node v16.8.0 craco: *** Cannot find ESLint loader (eslint-loader). ***

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eslint, craco

I am trying to start a project with node 16.8.0 (is an old project) taken from GitHub for a school project.  There seems to be a problem with craco, the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66113887/how-to-solve-craco-cannot-find-eslint-loader-eslint-loader-error-wi).
The solution described in the answer, does not work and the problem persists. Do you have any ideas? It seems somehow to be related with the plugins.

```
craco:  *** Cannot find ESLint loader (eslint-loader). ***
/Users/simple-demo-main/client/node_modules/@craco/craco/lib/features/webpack/style/postcss.js:54
                craPlugins = match.loader.options.plugins();
                                                  ^

TypeError: match.loader.options.plugins is not a function
    at extendsPostcss (/Users/simple-demo-main/client/node_modules/@craco/craco/lib/features/webpack/style/postcss.js:54:51)
    at overrideLoader (/Users/simple-demo-main/client/node_modules/@craco/craco/lib/features/webpack/style/postcss.js:97:9)
    at /Users/simple-demo-main/client/node_modules/@craco/craco/lib/features/webpack/style/postcss.js:118:13
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at overridePostcss (/Users/simple-demo-main/client/node_modules/@craco/craco/lib/features/webpack/style/postcss.js:117:17)
    at overrideStyle (/Users/simple-demo-main/client/node_modules/@craco/craco/lib/features/webpack/style/style.js:9:25)
    at mergeWebpackConfig (/Users/simple-demo-main/client/node_modules/@craco/craco/lib/features/webpack/merge-webpack-config.js:48:30)
    at overrideWebpackDev (/Users/simple-demo-main/client/node_modules/@craco/craco/lib/features/webpack/override.js:11:36)
    at /Users/simple-demo-main/client/node_modules/@craco/craco/scripts/start.js:24:5
```

Comment: try to add this to the craco.config.js https://github.com/dilanx/craco/issues/281#issuecomment-898941162